# 3 by 3 matrix Sudoku style

Tags: matrix, sudoku

I want to create a 3 by 3 matrix of numbers 1, 2, 3. Each digit should appear exactly once in each row and column (Sudoku style).

I know how to create the first line:

```
from random import sample
print(sample(range(0, 3), 3))
```

but have no clue how to continue from here...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sudoku {
    public int[][] grid;

    Sudoku(){
        grid = new int[3][3]; //empty
    }

    Sudoku(String start){  
        grid = new int[3][3];
        for(int x = 0; x <3; x++){
            for(int y =0; y<3; y++){
                grid[x][y] = 0;
            }
        }

        grid[0][0] = 1; //top left most
        grid[0][1] = 3;
        //grid[0][2] = 2;
        grid[1][0] = 3;
        grid[1][1] = 2;
        grid[1][2] = 1;
        grid[2][1] = 1;
        grid[2][2] = 3;
    }

    public void printMySudoku(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            if (i % 1 == 0)
                System.out.println(" -----------------------");
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
                if (j % 1 == 0) System.out.print("| ");
                System.out.print(grid[i][j] == 0
                        ? " "
                                : Integer.toString(grid[i][j]));

                System.out.print(' ');
            }
            System.out.println("|");
        }
        System.out.println(" -----------------------");

    }
    public boolean insertVal(int row, int col, int myVal){
        System.out.println("Entered insertVal " + "row " + row + "       column " + col + " myVal " + myVal);
        if(checkRow(row, col, myVal) == false) 
            return false;

        if(checkCol(row, col, myVal) == false)
            return false;

        if(checkBox(row, col, myVal) == false) 
            return false;

        grid[row][col] = myVal;


        return true;

    }
    public boolean removeVal(int row, int col, int myVal) {
        //grid[row][col]   = 0;

        return true;
    }
    private boolean checkRow(int row, int col, int myVal) {
        for (int a = 0; a < 3; ++a)  // row
            if (myVal == grid[row][a]){
                System.out.println(myVal + " Already in Row: " + row);
                return false;
            }
        return true;

    }
    private boolean checkCol(int row, int col, int myVal) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 3; ++b)  // column
            if (myVal == grid[b][col]){
                System.out.println(myVal + " Already in Column: " + col);  
                return false;
            }
        return true;

    }

    public boolean checkBox(int row, int col, int myVal) {
        int boxRowOffset = (row / 3)*3;
        int boxColOffset = (col / 3)*3;
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; ++c) // box
            for (int d = 0; d < 3; ++d)
                if (myVal == grid[boxRowOffset+c][boxColOffset+d]){
                    System.out.println(myVal + " Already in Box " );
                     return false;
                }
        return true;

    }




    public static void main(String args[]){

        Sudoku i = new Sudoku("start");
        i.printMySudoku();
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner guess = new Scanner(System.in);

        int row, col, val;
        String action;

        while(true){
            System.out.println("Enter I for insert or R for remove: ");
            action = guess.next();

            System.out.println("Row: ");
            row = guess.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Column: ");
            col = guess.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Value: ");
            val = guess.nextInt();

            if(action.equals("I")){
                if(i.insertVal(row, col, val)){
                    System.out.println("Good Job  ");
                }
                else System.out.println("Try Again ");
                i.printMySudoku();
            }
            else{ i.removeVal(row, col, val);
            i.printMySudoku();}

        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to go about it, by subsetting permutations:

```
from itertools import permutations

SIZE = 3

result = []

for p in permutations(range(1, SIZE + 1)):
    if all(p[i] != r for q in result for i, r in enumerate(q)):
        result.append(p)

for row in result:
    print(*row)
```

This is more complex than it needs to be to solve your problem as it allows you to change `SIZE`, eg. 9:

```
> python3 test.py
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2 1 4 3 6 5 8 9 7
3 4 1 2 7 8 9 5 6
4 3 2 1 8 9 6 7 5
5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4
6 5 8 9 1 7 3 4 2
7 8 9 5 2 3 4 6 1
8 9 6 7 4 2 5 1 3
9 7 5 6 3 4 1 2 8
>
```

You could throw in a `random.shuffle()` to mix things up a bit more.